# Como adicionar dados ao arquivo JSON em Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, angular-6

Tenho um código que envia e recebe mensagens. Consigo ler um arquivo JSON local

Com este código no ngOnInit consigo ler o que está dentro do arquivo JSON e transformar ele em uma mensagem que é exibida na tela:

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.emissor = 'Luis Henrique';
this._http.get<PreparacaoDeMensagem[]>("../assets/db/mensagem.json")
  .subscribe(mensagem => {
    this.mensagem = mensagem        
    for (let i=0;i < mensagem.length;i++){
      this.adicionarMensagem(this.mensagem[i]);
    }
})
```

Agora meu problema é: adicionar novos dados ao arquivo json, ele está assim:

```
[
{
    "texto": "Oi galera, como vocês estão?",
    "data": "2018-09-25T21:08:52",
    "contato": "José"
},
{
    "texto": "Estou bem, José, e você?",
    "data": "2018-09-25T21:08:52",
    "contato": "Maria"
},
{
    "texto": "Opa pessoal, tudo bem com vcs?",
    "data": "2018-09-25T21:08:52",
    "contato": "Luis Henrique"
},
{
    "texto": "Opa pessoal, tudo bem com vcs?",
    "data": "2018-09-25T21:08:52",
    "contato": "Luis Henrique"
},
{
    "texto": "Opa pessoal, tudo bem com vcs?",
    "data": "2018-09-25T21:08:52",
    "contato": "Luis Henrique"
}
```

Ja consigo transformar a mensagem em um formato que vai ser entendido pelo JSON usando a função JSON.stringify(), só preciso saber como dou um 'push' no arquivo json.

Segue o codigo que envia a mensagem e transforma ela em uma string json:

```
  enviar() {
    let mensagem = {
      texto: this.textoEmEdicao,
      data: new Date(),
      contato: this.emissor
    }
    this.adicionarMensagem(mensagem);
    this.textoEmEdicao = '';
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mensagem)) //Transforma em string json e mostra no console
 }
```

Comment: esse push seria salvar?

Comment: Não, seria algo como a função push em arrays no javascript, ela empurra as outras casas do array e adiciona uma nova

Comment: vc quer salvar na primira posição? na ultima ou em determinado loca?

Comment: Quero salvar em baixo das que já são existentes no código

Comment: luis so um post no arquio json n resolv?

Comment: axo que você via ter que passa em um backend

Answer (score 0):

Bem, talvez exista um pouco de confusão na hora de manipular objetos JSON.

Por exemplo, você pode simplesmente:

```
var todasMensagens:any = [
{
    "texto": "Oi galera, como vocês estão?",
    "data": "2018-09-25T21:08:52",
    "contato": "José"
},
{
    "texto": "Estou bem, José, e você?",
    "data": "2018-09-25T21:08:52",
    "contato": "Maria"
}]

let mensagem = {
      texto: this.textoEmEdicao,
      data: new Date(),
      contato: this.emissor
    }

todasMensagens.push(mensagem);
```

Nesse caso, o objeto "todasMensagens" armazenaria o JSON com todas as mensagens. Por ser um array, o método push já é oferecido. E se você declarar esse array do tipo any, você ainda consegue fazer push do que você bem entender. Por exemplo:

```
todasMensagens.push("texto");
todasMensagens.push(1);
todasMensagens.push([{array: "teste"}, {outroobjeto: "teste"}]);
```